# Where can I get a Cygwin /etc/skel directory

Tags: windows-7, cygwin

This is weird. I had to wipe my Windows 7 disk and am rebuilding it. I installed Cygwin and opened up the terminal. To my surprise, it did not start out by telling me it was copying the bash configuration files. When I did 'ls -a' on my HOME directory, there was no .bashrc. I figured I'd just copy it over from the /etc/skel directory, but when I changed to that directory it was empty. At this point I'm not sure what to do next. I know there are example files of .bashrc and .profile on the internet, but it would be nice if I could fill /etc/skel with the proper contents. I'm a little reluctant, but at this point I don't have a lot of time invested and could try uninstalling Cygwin and then reinstalling. Or I could just go get the example files from the internet because I'm going to be editing them anyway and don't need the /etc/skel to set up other users. Recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ find /etc/defaults -name "*bash*"
/etc/defaults/etc/bash.bashrc
/etc/defaults/etc/bash.bash_logout
/etc/defaults/etc/bash_completion.d
/etc/defaults/etc/skel/.bashrc
/etc/defaults/etc/skel/.bash_profile
```

these files are part of the `base-files` package

```
$ cygcheck -f /etc/defaults/etc/bash.bashrc /etc/defaults/etc/skel/.bash_profile
base-files-4.3-2
base-files-4.3-2
```

Comment: `$ find /etc/defaults -name "*bash*"` -> 
`File not found - *bash*` -- The `find` command is historically troublesome, because it is usually overwritten by Windows' `find`. Make sure you use the right one (i.e.`which find`), try `/usr/bin/find` instead, if Windows overrode it.

Comment: `$ /usr/bin/find /etc/defaults -name "*bash*"` -> `/usr/bin/find: '/etc/defaults': No such file or directory`